# SVG center horizontal and vertical line

Tags: css, svg, width, line

How can I create an SVG containing two lines (one horizontal, one vertical) going from the middle from one side to the middle of the opposite side, thus making a plus sign the same size as the SVG container?

This is what I have now but when changing SVG size the line lengths will not change

```
<svg width="10px" height="10px">
<line class="point" x1="0" x2="10" y1="5" y2="5" />
<line class="point" x1="5" x2="5" y1="0" y2="10" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Draw the line and then align `svg` in the center of its container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an SVG's contents to scale with its size, it needs to have a `viewBox`.

```css
svg {
  background-color: linen;
}

.point {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1;
}
```

```html
<svg width="10px" height="10px" viewBox="0 0 10 10">
<line class="point" x1="0" x2="10" y1="5" y2="5" />
<line class="point" x1="5" x2="5" y1="0" y2="10" />
</svg>

<svg width="30px" height="30px" viewBox="0 0 10 10">
<line class="point" x1="0" x2="10" y1="5" y2="5" />
<line class="point" x1="5" x2="5" y1="0" y2="10" />
</svg>

<svg width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 10 10">
<line class="point" x1="0" x2="10" y1="5" y2="5" />
<line class="point" x1="5" x2="5" y1="0" y2="10" />
</svg>
```

In this example, everything scales, including the line width.  If that's not what you want, then you can either use @SirExotic's approach (using percentage coordinates), or you could set the lines to not scale by using `vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke`.

```css
svg {
  background-color: linen;
}

.point {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1;
  vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke;
}
```

```html
<svg width="10px" height="10px" viewBox="0 0 10 10">
<line class="point" x1="0" x2="10" y1="5" y2="5" />
<line class="point" x1="5" x2="5" y1="0" y2="10" />
</svg>

<svg width="30px" height="30px" viewBox="0 0 10 10">
<line class="point" x1="0" x2="10" y1="5" y2="5" />
<line class="point" x1="5" x2="5" y1="0" y2="10" />
</svg>

<svg width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 10 10">
<line class="point" x1="0" x2="10" y1="5" y2="5" />
<line class="point" x1="5" x2="5" y1="0" y2="10" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

The container in this example is the `body`, but you can always wrap it in another container and set your desired `height` and `width`.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<svg height="100%" width="100%">
  <line x1="50%" y1="0" x2="50%" y2="100%" style="stroke:blue;stroke-width:1" />
    <line x1="0" y1="50%" x2="100%" y2="50%" style="stroke:blue;stroke-width:1" />
</svg>
```